# Android ViewPager refresh when swipe

Tags: android

My fragment is not refreshing when I swipe back, so I want to know how I can refresh it when I swipe it back. I have seen many different answers online, but I don't why they don't work in my situation. It would be highly appreciated if someone could help me out, thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                Profile tab1 = new Profile();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                Puzzles tab2 = new Puzzles();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Profile";
            case 1:
                return "Puzzles";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

I have tried `setOffscreenPageLimit(0)`, detach attach fragment in `onTabSelected`, using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, `notifyDataSetChanged()`, and even

```
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
return POSITION_NONE;
}
```

this doesn't work too. So I hope someone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to refresh the data in a particular `Fragment`, you have to do 2 things,

1. Store the updated data into `Activity`
2. Show the updated data in `onResume()` in that particular `Fragment`

If you want your data to be saved even after killing the app, store it in `SharedPreference`. Hope it helps!

Comment: How to custom the `ViewPager` class?

Comment: create an empty class and put all the code of `ViewPager` source. For instance, create an empty class named `CustomViewPager.Java` and copy all the codes of `ViewPager` and don't forget to make some small necessary changes

Comment: I have tried by adding a new class called `ViewPager`, but it doesn't work too.

Comment: make it have a different name, cause you might get confused (of which package it belongs)

Comment: but the `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);`shows error that the type is not correct

Comment: did you modify your xml?

Comment: Which XML please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137237/discussion-between-tahmid-rahman-and-androidnewbie).

Answer (score 0):

On your fragment class add this.

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {

     //Try adapter.notifyDataSetChanged or something like passing the new(updated) data to adapter from here.        

    }
}
```

Hope it helps.